# How to AutoFilter or similar to include only certain words

Tags: vba, excel, filter, autofilter

I understand I can use auto filter like this to remove certain rows that contain certain strings, as shown below (in this example the removed row contains string "111-11111").

```
Set ws = Sheets("Gate_Results")
Set rng1 = ws.Range(ws.[u1], ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "U").End(xlUp))
With ActiveSheet
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    rng1.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="111-11111"
    rng1.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Delete
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
```

However I was wondering if there was a way to remove strings that DO NOT contain the criteria. An example of this would be if string ###-##### represents product codes, if I want to filter my list to see only 3 different products out of a library of codes, could I use the AutoFilter function to do so, and if so how?

I tried the following (and similar example but &-ing in additional strings in the criteria1 section) already, however it did not work at all, but that was just my amateurish guesswork.

```
Set ws = Sheets("Gate_Results")
Set rng1 = ws.Range(ws.[u1], ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "U").End(xlUp))
With ActiveSheet
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    rng1.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:<>"111-11111"
    rng1.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Delete
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
```

I'd appreciate any help on finding a working method, even if it doesn't involve autofilter. But efficiency would be extra appreciated. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the `<>` between the inverted commas. So:

```
Set ws = Sheets("Gate_Results")
Set rng1 = ws.Range(ws.[u1], ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "U").End(xlUp))
With ActiveSheet
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    rng1.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:"<>111-11111"
    rng1.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Delete
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
```

Comment: I am getting "expected: named parameter" on 'Criteria1' error using this. Any ideas

Comment: On what line is the error occuring? Have you declared your variables?

Comment: I fixed the error, and your suggestion is working great, thanks, if I need any help with autofilter, is it ok to comment here?

Comment: You can, although you are perhaps better off posting a new question if you want others (and not only other commenters on this particular question) to be alerted in order to assist.

Comment: Ok, I will do that if you cannot assist me on this, I am back to working on your above code and I now realise that I don't know how I would do <> where "111-11111" is, instead, an array. Do you have any knowledge of this?

Comment: In the end, I used a less efficient method to achieve my goal, it turns out microsoft didnt implement a way for this to be done without the use of an advanced filter or helper column. My method was a cycle down list method, using using cells(cellcount, 7) and if = to # or # or.. else deleterow  . If the row was deleted the cellcount was left the same, if not +1 to cellcount. This method took 4 seconds to process 1300 results